# Magento view related products in list.phtml

Tags: magento

I have the following requirement;

I want to show a products configured **related products**  on the category listing page (list.phtml).
I figured I could make some call on the list.phtml inbetween the for each loop for each product using the [b]$_product[/b] variable but I can't seem to populate the relatedProductCollection
sorry new to all this is it even possible.

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as[b] $_product[/b]):?>
    <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?>last<?php endif; ?>" >
        <div class="product-shop">
            <div class="f-fix">


                     <?php  $product->getRelatedProductCollection(); ?>


    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**$product** has been used to call the getRelatedProductCollection function.

but,

In that foreach loop you have taken it as **$_product**.

Can you see the difference ??

**Underscore** is missing. This is taken from your code. Make the variable same in both the places and try.